# Keeping the score and level on the screen

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a side scrolling game where the camera follows my character. The level and score display is visible, but it stays in place and is no longer on-screen once I move. How can I make it to where the score and level display is "fixed" on the screen?

Here's part of the code that I'm focused on:

```
const scoreLabel = add([
    text(score),
    pos(15, 6),
    layer('ui'),
    {
        value: score,
    }
])

add([text('level' + parseInt(level + 1)), pos(40, 6)])
```

Comment: Are you using some JS game engine? Does it support GUIs? Also, you could simply add the current x offset to the position.

Comment: @ChrisG I'm actually using the Kaboom.js engine, and no its not GUI based.